# Does postgres optimize same expressions in CASE

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the number from text column of a database (for example the next text is `'Test 900 test'`)

```
select substring('Test 900 g' from '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*')
```

The in-text number can be float (from 0 to 1) or integer (>100) and I want to cast it to the single float format with `CASE` the following way

```
select case when substring('Test 900 g' from '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*')::numeric >= 100 
                 then substring('Test 900 g' from '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*')::numeric / 10000
            else substring('Test 900 g' from '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*')::numeric
       end as single_format
```

Will Postgres recalculate the substring value every time in this `CASE` construction or will this expression be optimized and calculated only one time for each row?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to answer for your query.

Expression should be calculated only once in the following query :

```
select case 
         when num >= 100 
         then num / 10000
         else num
       end as single_format
  from CAST(substring('Test 900 g' from '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*') AS numeric) AS num
```